# UninitializedPropertyAccessException in Android Studio with viewModel

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel

I'm New to Kotlin and Android Studio and trying to implement Room database with ViewModel now, but I face the problem *"kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property habitViewModel has not been initialized"*

I think that this is due to the early initialization of View Model, but I can't find the way to fix it.

This is my code below.

**Activity OnCreate Code**

```
class HabitActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding : ActivityHabitBinding
    lateinit var habitViewModel : HabitViewModel
    lateinit var habitAdapter: HabitAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityHabitBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        habitViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[habitViewModel::class.java]
        setContentView(binding.root)

        // view model
        habitViewModel.habitList.observe(this) {
            habitAdapter.update(it)
        }

        // adapter
        habitAdapter = HabitAdapter(this)
        binding.rvHabitList.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        binding.rvHabitList.adapter = habitAdapter

        
    }
```

**ViewModel code**

```
class HabitViewModel: ViewModel() {
    val habitList: LiveData<MutableList<HabitDTO>>
    private var habitRepository: HabitRepo = HabitRepo.get()


    init {
        habitList = habitRepository.list()
    }
}
```

**Build.Gradle dependencies**

```
def arch_version = "2.1.0"
    def lifecycle_version = "2.5.0-rc02"
    def roomVersion = "2.4.2"

    // Room
    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:$roomVersion")
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$roomVersion")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:$roomVersion")
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.9'
    kapt 'org.xerial:sqlite-jdbc:3.34.0'

    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version")
```

And This is my error message capture
[error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGBIK.png)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is this line, where you try to use an instance of the object you are initializing

```kotlin
habitViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[habitViewModel::class.java]
```

the argument there should be the class name, not the instance name

```kotlin
habitViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[HabitViewModel::class.java]
```

You can also use this syntax instead of the `lateinit var` approach to get the ViewModel in Kotlin if you have the right -ktx gradle dependencies (`implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.5.0'`)

```kotlin
private val habitViewModel: HabitViewModel by viewModels()
```